# Galaxy Note keeps duplicating my contacts

Tags: contacts, 4.2-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-note-2

My Galaxy Note 2 keeps duplicating my contacts; how can I stop this?

I ended up with over 35,000 contacts and it keeps growing as my phone keeps duplicating them a few hundred times. I have no contacts on my SIM card.

Comment: Is this your Google contacts or your phone contacts? And also are you using the stock contact app?

Comment: My phone contacts. Google contacts are fine. What is this app?

Comment: If I were you, I would transfer all of my contacts to Google contacts and then delete all of the phone contacts. I think that this might solve the problem.

Comment: Yes have them all in Google. In Google contacts there are not duplicates. I have deleted all the contacts but when I synch again I start have a growing number of contacts again.